# Ant task to determine if a file is readonly

Tags: ant, build, readonly, build.xml, ant-contrib

I need to write an ant task to determine if a certain file is readonly, and if it is, fail.  I would like to avoid using a custom selector to do this do to the nature of our build system.  Anyone have any ideas how to go about doing this? I'm using ant 1.8 + ant-contrib.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will something like this do the trick?

```
<condition property="file.is.readonly">
  <not>
    <isfileselected file="${the.file.in.question}">
      <writable />
    </isfileselected>
  </not>
</condition>
<fail if="file.is.readonly" message="${the.file.in.question} is not writeable" />
```

This uses the [`condition` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) and the [`isfileselected` condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) (not a direct link - you'll have to search down the page) combined with the [`writable` selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#writable) (and reversed with a `not` condition).

#### Update:

An possibly better alternative would be:

```
<fail message="${the.file.in.question} is not writeable">
  <condition>
    <not>
      <isfileselected file="${the.file.in.question}">
        <writable />
      </isfileselected>
    </not>
  </condition>
</fail>
```

This has the check and the fail as one distinct action rather than two, so you may find it clearer, and it doesn't require using a property name, so your namespace is cleaner.

Comment: Wow. You just solved my problem that I've spent a good number of hours on.  I actually understand what you did and I can replicate in in the future.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Justin @Arne if you copied the original version of this you'll need to change `writeable` to `writable` - I've only just tested it now and realised I made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better ways but I'll throw a few possible methods out there.

- Use the copy task to create a temp duplicate then attempt to copy this file to overwrite the original. The failonerror attribute will come in handy
- Use the java task to execute a task which executes some simple code such as:

  File f = new File( path );
  f.canWrite()......

Comment: the f.canWrite() is most definitely a viable option.  Is there a way to accomplish this using only built in ant/ant-contrib tasks?

Answer (score 0):

What about writing a [custom condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/custom-programming.html#customconditions) to be used by the [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) task? It is more flexible.

```
public class IsReadOnly extends ProjectComponent implements Condition
{
  private Resource resource;

  /**
   * The resource to test.
   */
  public void add(Resource r) {
    if (resource != null) {
        throw new BuildException("only one resource can be tested");
    }
    resource = r;
  }

  /**
   * Argument validation.
   */
  protected void validate() throws BuildException {
    if (resource == null) {
        throw new BuildException("resource is required");
    }
  }

  public boolean eval() {
    validate();
    if (resource instanceof FileProvider) {
      return !((FileProvider)resource).getFile().canWrite();
    }
    try {
      resource.getOutputStream();
      return false;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException no) {
      return false;
    } catch (IOException no) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Integrate with

```
<typedef
  name="isreadonly"
  classname="IsReadOnly"
  classpath="${myclasses}"/>
```

and use it like

```
<condition property="readonly">
  <isreadonly>
    <file file="${file}"/>
  </isreadonly>
</condition>
```